# Gulp watch causes infinite build loop

Tags: javascript, gulp

my gulp watch keeps on a rebuild after saving js file, the Scss file working well, the problem is when saving other files inside the project folder, changing or replacing images, triggers the rebuild to start and finish building dist folder.
only while saving Scss files, the build starts and finishes as accepted.

terminal output:

```
[17:53:11] Starting 'js-build'...
[17:53:11] Finished 'js-build' after 452 ms
[17:53:11] Starting 'js-build'...
[17:53:12] Finished 'js-build' after 614 ms
[17:53:12] Starting 'js-build'...
```

please advice?

my gulp code:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
    babel = require('gulp-babel');
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify-es').default,
    cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    gcmq = require('gulp-group-css-media-queries'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
    cache = require('gulp-cache'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    del = require('del'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    scss = require('gulp-scss'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    server = browserSync.create(),
    fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include');

function reload(done) {
    server.reload();
    done();
}

function serve(done) {
    server.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './dist'
        }
    });
    done();
}

gulp.task('html', function() {
    return gulp.src('*.html')
        .pipe(fileinclude({
            prefix: '@@',
            basepath: '@file'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});

var scssFiles = [
    './scss/**/*.scss',
    '!./node_modules/**',
    '!./dist/**',
];

var jsFiles = [
    '**/*.js',
    '!./node_modules/**',
    '!gulpfile.js',
    '!./dist/**',
];

var imgFiles = [
    '**/*.{jpg,png,jpeg,svg,gif,ico}',
    '!./node_modules/**',
    '!./dist/**',
];

var fontFiles = [
    'fonts/**/*.*',
    '!./node_modules/**',
    '!./dist/**',
];

gulp.task('scss', function() {
    var postCSSplugins = [
        autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 version'] }),
    ];

    return gulp.src(scssFiles)
        .pipe(sass())
        // .pipe(concat('app.css'))
        .pipe(plumber()) //if need unoptimezed file - comment this line
        .pipe(gcmq()) //if need unoptimezed file - comment this line
        .pipe(cssnano()) //if need unoptimezed file - comment this line
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css/'))
        .pipe(server.stream()) //if need unoptimezed file - comment this line
});

gulp.task('js-build', function () {
    return gulp.src(jsFiles)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['@babel/env']
        }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
});

gulp.task('img', function() {
    return gulp.src(imgFiles)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
});

gulp.task('font', function() {
    return gulp.src(fontFiles)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'))
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(scssFiles, gulp.series('scss'), reload);
    gulp.watch('*.html', gulp.series('html'));
    gulp.watch(jsFiles, gulp.series('js-build'));
    gulp.watch(imgFiles, gulp.series('img'));
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return del('./dist');
});

gulp.task('build', gulp.parallel('scss', 'html', 'js-build', 'img', 'font'));

gulp.task('serve', gulp.parallel('watch', serve));

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('clean', 'build', 'serve'));
```